Definition of non-interactive non-commiting encryption
I'm having trouble understanding the definition of non-interactive non-committing encryption (NINCE) from the paper Separating Random Oracle Proofs from Complexity Theoretic Proofs: The Non-committing Encryption Case by Jesper Buus Nielsen. This may be due to my lack of experience with MPC definitions. Could someone clarify how NINCE differs from the non-committing encryption scheme discussed in more recent works such as YKT19, YKXT20, BBD+20, etc. Thanks in advance.

An NINCE is a non-committing encryption scheme in which the encryption and decryption procedures are non-interactive, meaning that the receiver (decryptor) does not send messages to the sender (encryptor) during the encryption phase and the sender (encryptor) does not send messages to the receiver (decryptor) during the decryption phase. The recent works on NCE are similarly non-interactive.
The impossibility result of Nielsen states that if the public and secret keys are fixed, then only a bounded number of ciphertexts can be generated in a non-committing manner. In other words, to handle an unbounded number of non-committing encryptions, there must be interactions between the sender and receiver during the encryption/decryption phase. These interactions help the parties to update their respective keys or internal state.
The following are extracts from CPP20 and CHK05 that include brief remarks on Nielsen's results.

In fact, as noted by Nielsen [N02], any adaptively-secure scheme with non-interactive encryption must have a decryption key which is at least as long as the number of bits to be decrypted under this key. In a nutshell, this is because the simulator must “open” the “dummy ciphertexts” as encryptions of any given sequence of messages by presenting an appropriate secret key; therefore, the number of possible secret keys must be at least the number of possible message-sequences.


[Nie02] showed that any non-committing encryption, including bideniable encryption, can only reuse its public key an a prior bounded number of times; and therefore deniable communication must be interactive, even if two messages.

Recent works can handle only a single non-committing encryption where the size of the message is at most the size of the secret key.

Non-interactive non-committing encryption (NINCE) is an encryption scheme where a sender can send an encrypted message to a receiver without any interaction, and later, the sender can provide a "proof" that the message was any of several possible messages. This means the sender isn't committed to a specific message until they reveal the proof.
The key difference between NINCE and more recent non-committing encryption schemes (like those in YKT19, YKXT20, BBD+20) is the interaction aspect. NINCE is non-interactive, meaning no back-and-forth communication is needed during the encryption process. Recent schemes may allow some interaction to enhance security or efficiency, but the core idea of not committing to a specific message until the reveal remains the same.

The recent works are also non-interactive, i.e., the encryption process does not require any interaction with the receiver.
